# @After doesn't work (Cucumber with SenerityBDD)

Tags: java, cucumber-serenity

My issue: I am using Cucumber with senerityBDD JAVA. In my project, @after not working after scenario as senerity document i read.

My hook class:

```
package com.TestSuite;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    
import static com.netdreamers.utils.Performance.PerformanceController.*;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", tags = "@testCase")

public class TestSuite{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass(){
        System.out.println("Start BeforeClass");   
   }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
       System.out.println("Start AfterClas");   

    }

    @After
    public void afterScenario(){
        System.out.println("After Scenario");
    }
}
```

My Feature file:

```
Feature: Access to Url

  Background:

  Scenario Outline: Access to Url
    Given I access to the Url at line "<index>"
    Examples:
      | index |
      | 0     |
      | 1     |
```

As expectation, @after annotation should work, it should be called after scenario. So
Please someone could tell me the reason the @after annotation not work after 2 loop when the Scenario Ouline repeats for Examples table "index" variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `@After` only works in step code. Update your options to

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = 
        "com.testsuite.steps", tags = "@testCase" )
```

And move the after code to a new step class

```
 package com.testsuite.steps;

 import cucumber.api.java.After;

 public class TestSteps {
    
        @After
        public void afterScenario(){
            System.out.println("After Scenario");
        }
 }
```

Comment: how does it affect when i run test with mvn command line bro?

Comment: it doesnt matter if you run it on the command line or in an IDE, the cucumber framework will always look for the annotation in the step code

Comment: i don't understand this suggestion "And move the after code", could you tell me more detail?

Comment: made a small update. its pretty clear now...

Comment: As your suggestion, where should class TestSuite be placed ?

Comment: as your suggestion, i am facing issue: cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "..." is undefined
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST PENDING

Comment: thats a different issue for a new question

Comment: in my project having 2 package called steps placed at 2 different place. Could it cause error ?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?